# Cast negative number to unsigned types (ushort, uint or ulong)

Tags: c#, reflection

How to cast some negative number to `unsigned types`.

```
Type type = typeof (ushort);
short num = -100;

ushort num1 = unchecked ((ushort) num); //When type is known. Result 65436

ushort num2 = unchecked(Convert.ChangeType(num, type)); //Need here the same value
```

Comment: You're not using reflection in the second example.

Comment: "This code doesn't work" - in what way? What result do you expect, and what happened?

Comment: ChangeType returns object not ushort

Comment: Please update your post: There is no reflection in your code... There is also no explanation of whether it compile time error (with exact error message) or run-time error. Also explaining your actual goal may help too - very unclear what type of magic you expect from `Convert.ChangeType` so you can assign result to variable.

Comment: not really bad question. how ever the problem is runtime Overflow error. of course if you first cast object to ushort or change ushort to object to fix compile time error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only 4 types. so simply you can write your own method for that.

```
private static object CastToUnsigned(object number)
{
    Type type = number.GetType();
    unchecked
    {
        if (type == typeof(int)) return (uint)(int)number;
        if (type == typeof(long)) return (ulong)(long)number;
        if (type == typeof(short)) return (ushort)(short)number;
        if (type == typeof(sbyte)) return (byte)(sbyte)number;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is the test:

```
short sh = -100;
int i = -100;
long l = -100;

Console.WriteLine(CastToUnsigned(sh));
Console.WriteLine(CastToUnsigned(i));
Console.WriteLine(CastToUnsigned(l));
```

Outputs

```
65436
4294967196
18446744073709551516
```

---

**Update 10/10/2017**

with C# 7.1 pattern matching feature for generic types you can now use switch statement.

thanks to @quinmars for his suggestion.

```
private static object CastToUnsigned<T>(T number) where T : struct
{
    unchecked
    {
        switch (number)
        {
            case long xlong: return (ulong) xlong;
            case int xint: return (uint)xint;
            case short xshort: return (ushort) xshort;
            case sbyte xsbyte: return (byte) xsbyte;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Four times "check type, unbox, convert, box" is quite ugly. I wonder what the use is for this method.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i have updated the answer. this should work better now. i cant think any better than this any way this maybe an xy problem maybe not. OP probably having unknown type or thats just a practice.

Comment: I don't get it. Why did you use `unchecked`? Casting to unsigned type will not get overflow or anything. But casting from unsigned will get it..

Comment: @sotn you are correct. unchecked can be removed. I don't remember why I put this. I think because that time I saw OP had unchecked.

Comment: Actually on the second thought I had, you were correct :D because the default value for checked/unchecked is determined by compiler option `/checked` and forcing it to be `unchecked` is a good idea in a `/checked` environment. Because it will give `OverflowException` in `checked` scope for negative values..

Comment: +1, you should probably return number instead of null. If the input is already unsigned everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine using `unsafe` code you could always write a function like this and do the conversion using pointers:

```
public static unsafe TTo Convert<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom value) where TFrom : unmanaged where TTo : unmanaged
{
    if (sizeof(TFrom) != sizeof(TTo))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Source and target types must be the same size!");
    }
    return *(TTo*)&value;
}
```

which you'd use like this:

```cs
short num = -100;
ushort uNum = Convert<short, ushort>(num);
```

The benefits here being no boxing, no type checking, allocation free code and if you're bold and know what you're doing you could even remove the size checking to get a branch-less implementation.
Obvious drawbacks here are the `unsafe` keyword which often is a no-go in many business applications and the generic implementation would allow casting any unmanaged struct to any other unmanaged struct as long as `sizeof` says they're of the same size (not gonna dive into the whole `sizeof` vs `Marshal.SizeOf()` thing here). If you know you're only converting primitive integer types it should be fine though.

Comment: I think using `unsafe` can mean some JIT optimisations can't happen so this may end up ultimately slower in real implementations.  Also I believe that some of these type casting operations, for example uint from int, are code-free after compilation: as the tests posted by M.kazem Akhgary show, the bit value is unchanged.